# Java - trouble in calling a method

Tags: java, methods

I have a sorting method created in a class separate from the class I am currently working in.  The sorting method is a public static void method named:

```
public static void sortSelection(Comparable[] array, int n)
```

In the class where I currently work, entitled "Library", I wish to call upon this method as part of a *different* sorting method which I simply call "sort".  So, I have written as follows:

```
public void sort() {
sortSelection(CDCollection, numberOfCDs)
}
```

where CDCollection is an array, and numberOfCDs is an integer.  However, I get the error message:

"The method sortSelection(CD[], int) is undefined for the type Library"

If anyone knows whay may cause this error, I would greatly appreciate it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You call a static method on a class by providing the class name. Something like this:

```
public void sort() {
    OtherClassName.sortSelection(CDCollection, numberOfCDs)
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  But this yielded another error message: The method sortSelection(int[], int) in the type Helpclass is not applicable for the arguments (CD[], int)

Comment: Your CD class needs to implement the Comparable Interface.

Answer (score 1):

you need to call the other class before using its method

```
public void sort()
{
     ClassName.sortSelection(array, int);
}
```